# iOS app crashes with no error, just (lldb)

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, lldb

My application lately seems to randomly crash with no error or exceptions. The console just shows `(lldb)` in light blue. I have uncaught exception handling and still nothing. It happens at random times. I can do the same task over and over and sometimes it will happen and sometimes it won't. Also sometimes it will happen in random places within the application.

So far what I have read is it is possibly just the `lldb` debugger crashing and not my app however I haven't noticed it before.

Any ideas how to figure out what the cause of the crash is?

It seems to have started when I added MBProgressHUD to my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using crittercism and testflight crash reporting to help find the area where it was occurring. It looks like it was because I was running core data on a background thread.

Comment: Could you provide some more insight on this? I am experiencing the exact same problem and I don't have a solution. I am parsing a large (13MB) XML file into Core Data using a background thread so that the user can keep using my app while this runs. It randomly crashes with (lldb) and nothing else.

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth i would recommend using Crashlytics to find the exact cause and line number. I think i was initializing and running core data on a background thread then calling in on the main thread. I can't remember though for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I also just encountered a similar error - where I was just getting a blue lldb in the console with no additional info. However I was getting an exc_bad_access in the debug navigator so I knew it had to be a memory problem. I ended up tracing it to a release command I should not have been making . . .

Are you getting any details of the error in the debug navigator?

If yes please provide.

An over released object might explain why the app would be crashing at random times since (from what I understand) the system won't always immediately dealloc your object just because you sent it a release command however it will do it sooner or later.

Comment: No I am not. Also I am using ARC, so I don't deal with release.

Comment: Yup. It happened to me with a release command as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to fix this issue for the last 2 hours or so and I turned out I simply had a break point in Xcode. This might not be the case for you but if anyone stumbles upon this thread, check your breakpoints.
In Xcode click [this arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwjkj.png) then [right click your breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLvaL.png) and delete them.

Not sure if this will be helpful to anyone or if I was just being stupid, but save yourself 2 hours and check your breakpoints :)